# Logarithms - Find the solution of $\ln(x^2+1) = \ln(x) + 2$, how to isolate $x$ in a meaningful way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

When solving

> $\ln(x^2+1) = \ln(x) + 2$

I'm getting stuck at

> $e^2 = \dfrac{x^2+1}{x}$

How do I isolate $x$?

Comment: Write as a quadratic equation and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$e^2=\frac{x^2+1}{x}\Longleftrightarrow x^2-e^2x+1=0$$

and you have a simple quadratic to solve.

Comment: I think the OP doesn't know how to. Assuming he doesn't, I'd add the quadratic solution : $ax^2+bx+c$, the solutions are $ x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.

Comment: Don't worry, I do know about how to solve quadratic equations. ;-)